# Saving a existing CSV file as CSV file in Excel changes the encoding

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv, encoding

I have a CSV file which has **'á'** character in it. When i import this file using StreamReader in .NET, it shows correctly. But When i save same copy of the file as CSV from Excel save dialog and then import the new file in .NET using stream reader, 'á' character shows as **'�'.**

Encoding of both files is UTF-8 only when checked from stream encoding. Please suggest solution to this problem.

Comment: I don't have `streamreader`, but If I paste your sentence containing the  'á'  into Excel, and then save that as CSV or CSV-UTF8, and then open it in Notepad++, the  'á'  is preserved in the file. So it doesn't seem as if Excel is eliminating the  'á' .  Perhaps you are doing something different when saving the file?  If I save the file as CSV(MSDOS) or  CSV(Macintosh) the  'á'  is NOT preserved.  What version of Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Excel O365. In apps like excel, i can also see the character is preserved. The problem is when i read that new file using StreamReader in C#.Net,  its showing question mark in place of that character.  When i save file as CSV-Unicode, its fine. But when i save in regular CSV, this problem persists. I hope you are getting my point.

Comment: Again, I'm not familiar with `StreamReader`. But I see that, when Excel writes a `UTF-8 CSV`, it includes the optional `BOM` (`EF BB BF`) at the beginning of the file. Could `StreamReader` (or how you are using it) be having a problem with this?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld When i save it as CSV(UTF-8), it works fine. Problem is when i save it as CSV from menu.

Comment: If you don't specify `UTF-8`, it seems Excel will not place the  BOM at the beginning of the file. However, if Excel opens a CSV that includes the BOM, it seems it will preserve it on a Save unless you specify a non-UTF8 format.  Something else is going on in your process.

Comment: You can specify the encoding in [`StreamReader` ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_)